# uncrustify: how to force a trailing { after an else

Tags: uncrustify

I am running uncrustify version 0.69 on Ubuntu 12.04
I want this output

```
if () {
} else {
}
```

This mostly happens but I cannot get a forced trailing { on a naked else.
With this

```
if () {
} else
    statement;
```

It does NOT change it to this

```
if () {
} else {
    statement;
}
```

Rather, it is left alone and not modified.
Anyone have any ideas on what uncrustify option will force this?
thanks
oldunixguy